# HTML & Javascript - Simple English-French Dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, database, dictionary, local-storage

Please bear with my utter lack of programming knowledge. My goal is to publish a **simple** and **basic** English-French dictionary which would run **entirely locally**. It would have to be capable of processing user input to find corresponding *meaning*, *usage* and *etymology*, among a few hundreds of entries.

Here is a partly successful attempt which **only** returns the meaning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
        <title>English-French Dictionary</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script>
            if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
            {
                localStorage.setItem('Apple','Pomme');
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
            }

            function myFunction()
            {
                var entryVal = document.getElementById("entryInput");
                var entryId = entryVal.value;
                var entryResult = localStorage.getItem(entryId);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Result: " + entryResult;
            }
        </script>
        <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
        <input id="entryInput" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="myFunction()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Thus, my question would be how to enable multiple results?
And considering my terrible programming level, is there a better yet simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to provide the english word, translation to french, meaning, use, and etymology, you should be able to store this in Javascript. Then do a lookup when the user types something in.

For example, you'd have the structure:

```
var words = {
    "apple": {
        translation: "Pomme",
        meaning: "fruit, red, sweet",
        use: "For eating",
        etymology: "From middle english Appel"
    },
    "bowling": {
        translation: "Blah blah",
        meaning: "sport",
        use: "For recreation",
        etymology: "Some old sport"
    }
};
```

And your `myFunction` would perform the lookup:

```
function myFunction() {
    var entryVal = document.getElementById("entryInput");
    var entryId = entryVal.value.toLowerCase();
    if (entryId in words) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Translation: " + words[entryId].translation;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Not found";
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have the ability to generate this structure of information (word, translation, meaning, use, etymology).

Here's a demo of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Qsqqt/1/

I'm not exactly sure what you were using `localStorage` for in your code, but it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much Ian, your solution works perfectly! I can now focus on real linguistic work.

Comment: @Rosemary Cool, thanks! I actually just updated the fiddle (in case you used it or looked at it) because I forgot to remove the `onclick="myFunction();"` from the HTML - I bind the event in Javascript, to keep Javascript unobtrusive. I'm glad it works and helped you though. Let me know if you need more help, I'd be happy to look into whatever :)